# Meaning of removable discontinuity

Tags: calculus

If a function is defined differently at $x=0, x<0$ and $x>0$

Then what is meant by removable discontinuity?

Comment: Welcome to mathstackexchange.Removable discontinuity means discontinuos at finite number of points in the interval

Comment: It doesn't really have anything to do with the function being written down as piecewise or not. $f$ has a removable discontinuity at $c$ if $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ exists and is different from $f(c)$. We use the term "removable" because if you change $f(c)$ to be $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ then the resulting function is continuous at $c$. With other types of discontinuities you have to make larger changes to $f$ to make it continuous at the point.

Comment: @Gopalkrishna Nayak: That is not the standard meaning of "removable discontinuity". Removable discontinuity at a point means the function has a (finite) limit at the point that is not equal to the value of the function at the point. I believe there may be some variation among authors as to whether "limit exists at the point and the function is not defined at the point" qualifies, however.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Removable_discontinuity

Answer (score 5):

A removable discontinuity is defined as:

Consider a function $f(x)$, Here if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) $necessarily exists, but is neither equal to $f(a)$ or $f(a)$ is not defined.

In this case, therefore, it is possible to redefine the function in such a manner that $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$$ and thus making function continuous.

**Example**

$f(x)=\dfrac {x}x$ is discontinuous at $x=0$ ( *because $f(0)=\frac 00$, which is clearly undefined*)but if i rewrite it as $g(x)=\frac 11$ then it is not discontinuous at $x=0$, then it means discontinuity is removable at $x=0$.

notice that here limit exists.

**Note:**

$f(x)=g(x)$ everywhere but not at $x=0$